# Module load breaks view load (old code)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying out codeIgniter and the Modular Extension. So far I followed the installation instructions from [wiredesignz on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home). Now I'm trying the tutorial [HMVC: an Introduction and Application](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/) from NetTuts.

I'm doing this with the actual version of CodeIgniter 2.1 and the actual version of the Modular Extension (downloaded the .zip version from bitbucket).

All works fine until I'm trying to run a method from a controller of another module.

The setup in short is, that there's two modules (site & login). Within the site's controllers there's site.php (`/modules/site/controllers/site.php`) with a method that checks if a user is logged in. This method would exit the script execution if accessing the site without being logged in. As this method logically belongs to the login module, the author suggests moving it there. So it then is moved to `/modules/login/controllers/login.php`.

The problem now is, how to access the method of the login module from within the site module. The slightly adjusted code from the tutorial:

```
// modules/site/controllers/site.php

function __construct()  
{  
    // parent::Controller();
    // replaced with:
    parent::__construct();

    // modules::run('login/is_logged_in');
    // replaces with:
    $this->load->module('login')->is_logged_in();
}
```

Like this I'm getting an error:

> Unable to load the requested file: logged_in_area.php

The method in question is inside the site module as well:

```
// modules/site/controllers/site.php

function members_area()
{
$this->load->view('logged_in_area');
}
```

The Script executes right until the `load->view` line and produces the error. There's no problem accessing the `logged_in_area.php` with running the `is_logged_in` method from within the site controller with the line:

```
$this->is_logged_in();
```

Any ideas?

**edit:**

the application tree:

```
/application
  /...
  /modules
    /login
      /controllers
        login.php
      /models
      /views
        login_form.php
        signup_form.php
        signup_successful.php
    /site
      /controllers
        site.php
      /models
        membership_model.php
      /views
        logged_in_area.php
```

PS: How can I get more INformation about the error? CodeIgniter seems to be very reserved about error output ...

Comment: In index.php, the frontcroller, there's a line where you define your environment.  Make sure that line says `define('ENVIRONMENT','development');`.  This way, you will get all errors.

Comment: It's set to `development`. Error reporting is `E_ALL`. Didn't change anything there.

Comment: I think however, you should not be loading views from other modules.  I thought the concept of modular extension was that you could call other controllers, not other views.  I made a library to handle my loginstate and everything.  This way you can use it everywhere.  You can then still make a module to show the loginforms and everything.

Comment: I'm not loading a view from another module, but a method for checking a login status. This seems logical to me. The view I'm trying to load is in the same module as the calling method (of that view). But, I'll take the hint towards libraries. Next thing I'll be looking into.

Comment: Well then I can't help you any further.  What you are doing also seems logical and valid to me.  Haven't used HMVC myself.  You could try adding some debug_statements to MX_Loader.  You could check the logfiles, there could be a lot of info in it.

Comment: Where is `logged_in_area.php` placed? In the 'Site' or 'Login' module?

Comment: `logged_in_area.php` is located inside `modules/site/views`. I'll add the whole tree above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) to load a view from within another module, you need to use an extended MX controller and a method:

`<?php echo Modules::run('module/controller/method', $param, $...); ?>`

Comment: And there we go! I had my site.php extend the `CI_Controller`. Replacing it with `MX_Controller` did the trick. But still, I don't load the view from another module! And with simple `CI_Controller` the "cross-module" load of another Controller works ... well ... don't have to understand everything ...