# Creating a filter from parent class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and I want to create some sort of filter to know when a user may/may not access a current controller

If anyone has any idea how to implement this in a different manner, great, but what I was thinking (and trying to do) is the following:

CI_Controller - which is the basic CodeIgniter controller class

MY_Controller - the basic controller which I use which extends CI_Controller

[Controller] - any "physical" controller

what i've tried to do is:

MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    private static $namespace = null;

    private static $permission = array('site', 'settings');

    public function __construct(){
        if ((!isset($_SESSION['user'])) && (in_array(__CLASS__, $permission))){
            throw new Exception('Unauthorized');
        }
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

obviously, this doesn't work as **CLASS** will always be that of MY_Controller and not that of the child object... and **NAMESPACE** doesn't work aswell.

Anyone has any idea? because Id really hate to start putting this snippet of code in every other class, and I'll prolly need the filtering later for some more elaborate things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following manner... simply in the constructor, I defined the current class

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    private static $permission = array('site', 'settings');
    public function __construct($currentController = __CLASS__){
        if ((!isset($_SESSION['user'])) && (in_array($currentController , $permission))){
            throw new Exception('Unauthorized');
        }
        parent::Controller();
    }
}
```

when calling the physical controller, we simply write as follows

```
class PhysicalController extends MY_Controller{

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(__CLASS__);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As there's no answer so far, maybe this suggestion might help. It's a different approach, though, that uses the Modular Extensions - HMVC ...

Like this you can have a module "login" with a controller that holds some methods to log a user in, to check session status and to log a user out (and the like).

In each other module you can now load the module login and check for the status and redirect if needed ...

There's a tutorial [HMVC: an Introduction and Application](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/hvmc-an-introduction-and-application/) I followed on nettuts that shows how to do the [CodeIgniter From Scratch: Day 6 – Login](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-6-login/) in that way. Maybe that helps. I had some difficulties as it's with an old codeigniter version. So maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462377/module-load-breaks-view-load-old-code) helps.

It's not how you're trying to do things, but maybe it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it but what I saw in [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/74784/#584038) forum might be working for you. The predicted code is:

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller{
    private static $permission = array('site', 'settings');
    public function __construct(){
        if ((!isset($_SESSION['user'])) && (in_array(__CLASS__, $permission))){
            throw new Exception('Unauthorized');
        }
        parent::Controller();
    }
}
```

But then you'd need to use

```
class My_controller extends MY_Controller
```

instead of

```
class My_controller extends Controller
```